Date formatter returning IndexOutOfBoundsException when setting string length
created date formatter that takes in string and concatenates slashes at specific points. However, I am trying to limit the length of the string using cleanInput.substring(4, 8) and get out of bounds error
   internal class DateFormatter {

    override fun format(input: String): String {
        if (input.isBlank()) return ""
        // logic to format date
        val cleanInput = input.replace("/", "")
        val textLength = cleanInput.length

        var result = ""
        result = if (textLength >= 2 && textLength < 4) {
            cleanInput.substring(0, 2) + "/" + cleanInput.substring(2)
        } else if (textLength >= 5) {
            cleanInput.substring(0, 2) +
                "/" + cleanInput.substring(2, 4) + "/" +
                cleanInput.substring(4, 8)
        } else if (input.last() == '/') {
            input.substring(0, input.length - 1)
        } else {
            input
        }

        return result
    }
}


Can you share how your input: String looks like?

the input:String would be numbers typed in a text field ex. 12302024 @JonathanStellwag

I cannot reproduce the issue, calling the function with 12302024 returns 12/30/2024, without an exception.

The error you describe is happening because you check for (textLength >= 5), which means that a string of 6 or 7 characters can get into that branch. You then use cleanInput.substring(4, 8), which is only OK if the string has 8 characters - apparently, your input doesn't. You should be checking for textlength = 8 instead if you're going to try to access the 8th character, or at least textlength > 7.
